# Stacked barplot, for each row of dataset

Tags: r, plot, bigdata, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to create stacked barplots using a large dataset (80,000 lines).

```
  POS         C1       C2     SELF    
1   1   0.546982 0.256896 0.196122    
2   2   0.628456 0.263229 0.108315    
3   3   0.652629 0.256041 0.091330    
4   4   0.562783 0.264318 0.172898    
5   5   0.562783 0.264318 0.172898    
6   6   0.180272 0.571032 0.248696
```

80.000

I've imported my csv file using `read.csv` and convert in a matrix using `as.matrix()`. I tried to plot using barplot using:

```
barplot(as.matrix(C3_GO2_06))
```

But I got a plot like that:

[image]

I need each row in POS to be a sample...i.e the column POS should be the x axes, and values associated with C1, C2, SELF stacked... but I don't know how to do that. Is necessary to convert to data frame?

Comment: How many unique values do we have in POS: `length(unique(C3_GO2_06$POS)` ?

Comment: try `barplot(t(as.matrix(C3_GO2_06)[,-1]))`

Comment: length(unique(C3_GO2_06$POS)) = 79879

Comment: Has the issue been solved?